# android content provider sum query

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to use `getContentResolver().query()` when I want `sum(column)`?

OR

Do I have to make raw query to db handle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, it seems that its not possible using `getContentResolver().query()`.
I had to get db connection and make `rawQuery`.

```
 ContentProviderClient client =  getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(AUTHORITY);
 SQLiteDatabase dbHandle= ((MyContentProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider()).getDbHandle();
 Cursor cursor = dbHandle.rawQuery("SELECT sum("+COLUM_NNAME+") FROM "+TABLE_NAME +" WHERE "+WHERE_CLAUSE , null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 int cnt =  cursor.getInt(0);
 cursor.close();
 cursor.deactivate();
 client.release();
```

Answer (score 6):

When providing the array of columns to `ContentResolver.query`, wrap the column name with the `sum()` function

```java
String[] columns = new String[] { "sum(" + columnName + ")" };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    content_uri,
    columns,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    sort
);

cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnSum = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Comment: this is not working Invalid column sum(duration)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2917):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.computeProjection(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:523)

Answer (score 3):

**ACCEPTED ANSWER IS WRONG**

**IT IS POSSIBLE IN CONTENTPROVIDER AS**

```
 String[] columns = new String[] { "sum(" + columnName + ")" };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        content_uri,
        columns,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        sort
    );
int columnSum = cursor.getInt(0);
```

Only mistake Tom did is he forget to do :

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: That Tom always making mistakes ;P

Answer (score 0):

You could use the '[simpleQueryForLong()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#simpleQueryForLong%28%29)'-Method.