# rawQuery a ContentProvider from an external app using a ContentProviderClient

Tags: mysql, group-by, android-contentprovider

I have been struggling with an issue for a couple of days. I am sharing a Content Provider with two different apps (app A and app B). All the stuff regarding DB creation and Content Provider management is done by app A. App B just accesses it using the corresponding Authorities and a Content Provider Client.

```
ContentProviderClient myCPClient = this.miContext.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(this.miUri);
```

The problem comes up when trying to query the database in a more complex way, i.e. using some key words like GROUP BY, HAVING, etc. I need to get unique references according to one specific column (I want to use GROUP BY), and I have found out that there is no `rawQuery()` method for a `ContentProviderClient`, but a simplified `query()` method (compared to the one available in the class `SQLiteDatabase`, which allows to formulate proper MySQL commands).

I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5872555/3247082), but since my ContentProvider is accessed from a different app, I do not have any class like `MyContentProvider`.

To sum up, is there any way to make a proper query (like `rawQuery()`) to a ContentProvider which was generated by a different app?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally got to a solution which is rather simple and sensible. I got a very good explanation about Content Providers and Content Resolvers. The latter is used to access the former, which means that they can not control what is in the provider, but get data from them. This means that you can not make a Content Provider Client to use a `rawQuery()` if it is not implemented (override) in the `query()` method of the corresponding `ContentProvider`.

To work around my problem, I have used a flag in my provider client and modify my content provider to read it so I can make use of GROUP BY. I just wanted to get unique references from the database according to a particular column.

Here it is the solution, which is not a very clean one, but it works quite well. 
For the `ContentProviderClient`,

```
ContentProviderClient myCPClient = this.miContext.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(this.miUri);
//I declare some variables for the query
//'selection' will get all the rows whose "_id" is greater than 0, i.e. all the rows
String selection = BaseDatosParam.Tabla._ID + ">?";
String[] selectionArgs = {"0"};
//'groupBy' is not formatted in any particular way. I just need it to contain the     pattern "GROUP BY"
String groupBy = "GROUP BY" + BaseDatosParam.Tabla.REF; 
//the last field of the query corresponds to 'sortOrder', but I 
Cursor c = myCPClient.query(Uri.parse(miUri.toString()),
                projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy);
```

In the `ContentProvider`,

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) 
{
    String where = selection;
    String groupBy = null;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.miBDManager.getWritableDatabase();
    //We just check out whether 'sortOrder' includes the pattern "GROUP BY", otherwise that field will remain null
    Pattern myPat = Pattern.compile("GROUP BY");
    Matcher myMat = myPat.matcher(sortOrder);
    if (myMat.find())
        groupBy = myMat.replaceFirst(""); 

    Cursor c = db.query(BaseDatosParam.Tabla.NOMBRE_TABLA, projection, where, selectionArgs, groupBy, null, null);
    c.setNotificationUri(this.getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return c;
}
```

Regards,