# How to join ContentProvider tables through rawQuery?

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I want to make sql join through rawQuery.

For example the uri's are as follow:

```
Uri mmsPartUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part"); 
Uri mmsInboxUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/inbox");


SQLiteDatabase db = //how to get it?
```

I imagine the query would look like similar to this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT mms.part.mid, mms.part.text, mms.inbox.m_id, mms.inbox.date FROM mms.part JOIN mms.inbox
             ON mms.part.mid = mms.inbox.m_id", null);
```

Is it possible? Then how? If not is there any other option to join tables, or do I have to use two Cursors and CursorJoiner to get similar result?

If join is not possible across different content providers, I'm curious if I can do any rawQueris like this:

```
Uri mmsPartUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/part");
SQLiteDatabase db = //how to get it?
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT mms.part.mid, mms.part.text,  FROM mms.part", null);
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843202/how-do-i-combine-data-from-two-separate-tables-into-a-single-cursor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854343/android-content-provider-sum-query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to join ContentProvider tables through rawQuery?

There is no `rawQuery()` available to clients of a `ContentProvider`.

You do not have access to the `SQLiteDatabase`, in part because there is no requirement that there *be* a SQLite database. A `ContentProvider` is a facade. Just as a Web service could be backed by any number of database technologies, so can a `ContentProvider`.

> Is it possible?

No.

> do I have to use two Cursors and CursorJoiner to get similar result?

Whether `CursorJoiner` will meet your needs, I cannot say. However, you will have to do the join on the client side, in your app. This is similar to a Web service, where any joins not already supported by the Web service need to be manually assembled on the client side.